# explain Ruby method gsub/scan

Tags: ruby, gsub

I am trying to get an explanation to what is happening in this line of code:

```
info["phone"] = info["phone"].gsub!(/\D/,"").scan(/1?(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/).join('.')
```

If a phone number is given such as 1-999-999-9999, (999)999-9999, or any combination put there.

Comment: Related (not duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253896/2988

Comment: That code isn't correctly written to start. The regex can be figured out by reading through the Regexp documentation and/or using [one of the many](https://www.regex101.com/r/xO3iJ7/1) Regular Expression parsers on the internet. Glance at `scan` and `join` and you'll be done.

Answer (score 3):

[`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-gsub) is used to replace a specific text with another string.  For example, `"hello world".gsub(/hello/, "goodbye")` would result in `"goodbye world"`.  The non-bang variant, `gsub`, does not modify the string itself; whereas the bang variant, `gsub!`, does:

```
test = "hello world"
test.gsub(/h[ae]ll[ou]/, "goodbye") # => "goodbye world"
test # => "hello world"
test.gsub!(/h[ae]ll[ou]/, "goodbye") # => "goodbye world"
test # => "goodbye world"
```

[`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-scan) "scans" the string for a certain pattern, and returns an array of occurrences.  This is useful for extracting certain things from a string:

```
tweet = "@github @you hello, world!"
tweet.scan(/@[\w]+/) # => ["@github", "@you"]
```

However, if you include groups within the scan, it returns an array of an array of group matches:

```
tweet.scan(/@([\w]+)/) # => [["github", "you"]]
```

So, what `.gsub!(/\D/, "")` does is it removes all non-digit characters from the string, and modifies the string (this last bit isn't really important right now).  `.scan` looks for a phone number from the input (a phone number being an optional 1, followed by a set of three digits, followed by a set of three digits, followed by a set of four digits).  Since it removes all non-digits from the input, it will attempt create a phone number from the first 10 or 11 numbers in the input, and for every 10 or 11 numbers past that.

However, the [join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) joins together the sets of digits into a single string, `999.999.9999`.  But if there are multiple phone numbers in the input, it will end up joining those phone numbers with a period, too.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`info["phone"] = info["phone"].stuff` - replace the original in the array/hash/whatever

`.gsub!(/\D/,"")` - remove all non-Digits, such as parentheses or hyphens. (note that you don't need the ! in the gsub!)

`.scan(/1?(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/)` - Country code of 1 at the beginning. Then three digits are in the first matching group. Then three digits in the second matching group, then 4 in the last. The groups get put into an Array.

`.join('.')` - combine all elements of the array and make a string with dots between.

So...

`'1+(555)123-4567'` would get changed to `'555.123.4567'`